# Add an auto incremented field to a mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with records that consist of:
_id
Name
Job
Phone

I'd like to be able to add a field with an auto incremented number to these records that already exist.

Ideally I'd like to end up with something like:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("53859768963e5e395d8b76e0"),
"Name": "Patricia",
"Job": "Admin"
"Phone": 02039393783
"UserID": 1

"_id" : ObjectId("53859768963e5e395d8b76e0"),
"Name": "Jonathan",
"Job": "Boss"
"Phone": 02039393783
"UserID": 2

"_id" : ObjectId("53859768963e5e395d8b76e0"),
"Name": "Trevor",
"Job": "Driver"
"Phone": 02039393783
"UserID": 3
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can loop the existing records and use the Counters Collection technique outlined here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/

And of course use update/$set instead of insert.